# after add component link error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i create test react project. Add modules and my packege.json look like:

```
    {
  "name": "untitled",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-node5": "^12.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.22.0",
    "history": "^4.6.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-native": "^0.42.3",
    "react-router": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router-config": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "react-router-native": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build": "babel input.js -o compiled.js"
  }
}
```

and webpack.config.js

```
var config = {
    entry: './index.js',

    output: {
        path:'/',
        filename: 'index.js',
    },

    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 8080
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', "node5", "stage-1", 'react', "stage-0"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

in my component i import component Link from react-router-native and after this adding react show error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export' but if i delete this string project work well. it's not the only component in the module, i can add any components like Promt, Route or Router. Why it's not work with Link?

This is code where error reproduced

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Router } from 'react-router';
import { Promt } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-native';

import logo from '../../logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The word `export` doesn't appear anywhere in the code you posted. The error is somewhere else. Doesn't the error message have a filename and line number in it?

Comment: Can you please share the relevant piece of source code where the error occurs?

Comment: what is the full filename of the file containing the export ? (file extension included)

Comment: @realseanp name is App.jsx

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the regular expression for the `test` value in your web pack config to be `test: /(\.js|\.jsx)$/`

Right now you are telling webpack to only run `.js` files through babel loader, but you aren't telling it to also run `.jsx` files through babel loader.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately the error remained